# Create HTML elements with php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a image-heavy WordPress site. To help with loading, I'm using lazy loading.

The lazyload plugin requires the img url in a `data-original` attribute.

I'm changing the `img` element using the function to add the image url to `data-original` and the placeholder to the `src`:

```
function add_lazyload($content) {
     $dom = new DOMDocument();
     @$dom->loadHTML($content);

     foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
         $oldsrc = $node->getAttribute('src');
         $node->setAttribute("data-original", $oldsrc );
         $newsrc = ''.get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/nothing.gif';
         $node->setAttribute("src", $newsrc);
         //create img tag
                 $element = $dom->createElement("img");
                 $dom->appendChild($element);

     }
     $newHtml = $dom->saveHtml();
     return $newHtml;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'add_lazyload');
```

The lazyloading is working but I wanted to add a non-JavaScript fallback. Is it possible with the above function to create a new `img` element using the `src` from the original `img`?

So the new `img` element would look like this:

```
<noscript><img src="img/example.jpg" width="640" heigh="480"></noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. As stated [here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_noscript.html), you just need to append the `<noscript>` part after your image.

Your code would then look like this:

```
function add_lazyload($content) {
     $dom = new DOMDocument();
     @$dom->loadHTML($content);

     foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
         $oldsrc = $node->getAttribute('src');
         $node->setAttribute("data-original", $oldsrc );
         $newsrc = ''.get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/nothing.gif';
         $node->setAttribute("src", $newsrc);
         //create img tag
         $element = $dom->createElement("img");
         $dom->appendChild($element);
         // add the <noscript> fallback for this image
         $dom->appendChild('<noscript><img src="img/example.jpg" width="640" heigh="480"></noscript>');

     }
     $newHtml = $dom->saveHtml();
     return $newHtml;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'add_lazyload');
```

Comment: cassi.lup - This is how I was trying to do it but it causes a fatal error and the page doesn't load. Also I would have to use the src of the original image something like - $dom->appendChild('<noscript><img src="'.$oldsrc.'" width="640" heigh="480"></noscript>');